# Tensorflow activation functions

Tags: python, api, tensorflow

We can call `tf.nn.relu` or `tf.nn.softplus`and so on.

I also saw the `tf.tanh`.

Is there a Inverse Hyperbolic Tangent function in the Tensorflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can express it as:

```
artanh(x) = 1/2 * ln ((1 + x)/(1 - x))
```

see: [Inverse functions as logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms)